# How to autoloading my classes alongside with composer autoloader?

Tags: php, composer-php

By considering this files structure

```
| -- src /
        | -- vendor
        | -- models
        | -- libraries
        | -- ...
        | -- composer.json
```

How can I autoload classes located in 'models' & 'libraries' directories ?

Comment: You typically include _two_ autoloader files / implementations: the one created by composer and your own.

Comment: I was thinking that PHP allows only one autoloader (I don't know from where this idea comes !), I test the  two autoloaders and they work fine, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add your own autoloader rules into the composer.json file in your project - this adds your own rules to the `vendor/autoload.php` file so that your own classes will load as well as the ones in the `vendor/` directory.  There's more information in the docs here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload.  Take a look at the PSR-0 section to load classes from your two directories.

Try something like:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": ["models/", "libraries"] }
    }
}
```

If your classes are namespaced, then specify the namespaces as this will stop composer from looking for *all* classes in those directories.

Comment: I don't know why but things don't want to work with "psr-0", but it works fine with psr-4: "psr-4": { "namespace1\\": "models/", "namespace2\\": "libraries/" } ... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Or later in code you can add your lib, example:

```
$loader = require(ROOTDIR . 'vendor/autoload.php'); // composer autoloading
//public function addPsr4($prefix, $paths, $prepend = false)
$loader->addPsr4('extend\\', ROOTDIR . 'class/lib'); 

$a = new \extend\MyClass(); // MyClass.php is in ROOTDIR/class/lib directory
```